# Subtraction of two data-points always results in 0, regardless of data

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

I'm working with some financial data from Yahoo.

My code is

```
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
library(astsa)
library(fGarch)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("^gspc",src='yahoo')

adj <- GSPC[, "GSPC.Adjusted", drop = FALSE]
n <- nrow(adj)
simpleReturn <- (adj[2:n,1] - adj[1:(n-1),1]) / adj[1:(n-1),1]
```

simpleReturn is a table full of zeros
I checked and even adj[2,1] - adj[1,1] results in zero, while it should be 1.74

I expected the code to return the simple rate of return for all data-points past the first one

Answer (score 1):

`getSymbols()` returns an xts object, which is a time series. All operations on time series data should be aligned by the timestamp and xts does this for you. Converting to a class that isn't time series creates the potential for many issues.

You can use the `ROC()` function to calculate the rate-of-change.

```r
simpleReturn <- ROC(adj, type = "discrete")
head(simpleReturn)
##            GSPC.Adjusted
## 2007-01-03            NA
## 2007-01-04   0.001228286
## 2007-01-05  -0.006084581
## 2007-01-08   0.002220318
## 2007-01-09  -0.000516676
## 2007-01-10   0.001940352
```

Notice how the result for 2007-01-04 is `0.0012` but it's `-0.00608` in AndS's answer. That's because their result uses data from the future, before you could have known it. This is one example of a serious issue that can happen when you don't use a time series class for time series data.

I strongly recommend you use a time series class for time series data. You can find lots of choices in the [CRAN Time Series Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

---

EDIT: also, notice that 4 of the 5 packages you loaded use time series classes: zoo (tseries, forecast), xts (quantmod), timeSeries (fGarch).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is something weird with the class/data type such that simple subtraction does not work as expected. I converted to a tibble and calculated everything just fine:

```r
library(tidyverse)

as_tibble(adj) |>
  mutate(date = date(adj),
         simple = (lead(GSPC.Adjusted)-GSPC.Adjusted)/GSPC.Adjusted)
#> # A tibble: 4,235 x 3
#>    GSPC.Adjusted date          simple
#>            <dbl> <date>         <dbl>
#>  1         1417. 2007-01-03  0.00123 
#>  2         1418. 2007-01-04 -0.00608 
#>  3         1410. 2007-01-05  0.00222 
#>  4         1413. 2007-01-08 -0.000517
#>  5         1412. 2007-01-09  0.00194 
#>  6         1415. 2007-01-10  0.00634 
#>  7         1424. 2007-01-11  0.00485 
#>  8         1431. 2007-01-12  0.000818
#>  9         1432. 2007-01-16 -0.000894
#> 10         1431. 2007-01-17 -0.00297 
#> # i 4,225 more rows
```

Comment: Yeah I found the solution. Data was saved in a weird library-specific format. Converting it to another data type solved the issue.

Comment: It's an xts object and simple subtraction doesn't work as expected because it has the potential to create results that use data that didn't exist at each point in time. Your answer does this and provides incorrect results. See my answer for details.